# SAS--How to identify the event occurred in three consecutive years?

Tags: date, sas

I am trying to identify traders who place transactions in the same month in each of three consecutive years in one company. Once a trader meets the criteria, these three transactions and all his subsequent transactions in that same month in that company should be identified.

Assume I have a sample data below.

```
data have;
input ID  STOCK   trandate $12.;
datalines;
1    1   10/15/2009
1    1   01/01/2010
1    1   01/10/2011
1    1   01/15/2012
1    1   01/01/2013
1    2   01/30/2011
1    2   01/30/2012
1    2   01/30/2012
1    2   01/30/2013
1    2   01/30/2014
1    2   01/30/2015
2    1   01/20/2010
2    1   01/15/2011
2    1   01/16/2012
2    1   02/01/2013
2    2   02/01/2010
2    2   02/10/2011
2    2   02/10/2012
2    2   02/10/2013
2    2   02/10/2014
2    2   01/10/2015
;
run;
```

What I need:

```
ID Stock  trandate type
1    1   10/15/2009 0
1    1   01/01/2010 1
1    1   01/10/2011 1
1    1   01/15/2012 1
1    1   01/01/2013 1
1    2   01/30/2011 1
1    2   01/30/2012 1
1    2   01/30/2012 1
1    2   01/30/2013 1
1    2   01/30/2014 1
1    2   01/30/2015 1
2    1   01/20/2010 0
2    1   01/15/2011 0
2    1   01/16/2012 0
2    1   02/01/2013 0
2    2   02/01/2010 1
2    2   02/10/2011 1
2    2   02/10/2012 1
2    2   02/10/2013 1
2    2   02/10/2014 1
2    2   01/10/2015 0
```

I used following code to achieve this:

```
proc sort data=have;
by id stock trandate;
run;

data have;
set have;
month=month(trandate);
year=year(trandate);
run;

proc sort data=have;
by  id stock month year;
run;

data have;
set have;
by personid secid month year;

  rungroup + (first.month or not first.month and year - lag(year) > 1);

run;


data temp;
  do index = 1 by 1 until (last.rungroup);
    set have;
    by rungroup;

    * distinct number of years in rungroup;
    years_runlength = sum (years_runlength, first.rungroup or year ne lag(year));
  end;

  do index = 1 to index;
    set have;
    if years_runlength >=4 then output;
  end;
run;
```

The above codes are used to identify traders with transactions in the past three consecutive years. Since I also need the subsequent transactions of these traders. The following codes are further applied.

```
proc sort data=temp;
by personid  secid   rungroup;
run;


data temp;
set temp;
by  rungroup;
if  first.rungroup then fyear=year;
run;

data temp(drop=fyear rename=(Locf=fyear));
 do until (last.personid);
   set  temp;
   by id stock;
   locf=coalesce(fyear,locf);
   output;
 end;
run;

data temp;
set temp;
by rungroup;
if first.rungroup then fmonth=month;
run;


data temp;
set temp;
gap=year-fyear;
run;


proc means data=temp;
var gap;
run;

data temp;
set temp;
if gap=3 then type2=1;
type1=1;
run;
```

The above codes are used to mark the first transaction after the three consecutive years. In this context, when the identified transactions combine with the original dataset, all transactions in that same month below the marked transaction could be identified. Thereby, I can achieve the objective that "these three transactions and all his subsequent transactions in that same month in that company should be identified". The following codes are used to achieve this.

```
proc sort data=have;
by id stock   rungroup;
run; 
proc sort data=temp;
by id stock   rungroup;
run; 



data combine;
merge have temp;
by id stock   rungroup;
run;


data combine;
set combine;
month=month(trandate);
run;



data combine1 (drop=fmonth rename=(Locf=fmonth));
 do until (last.personid );
   set  combine;
   by id stock;
   locf=coalesce(fmonth,locf);
   output;
 end;
run;


data combine2 (drop=type2 rename=(Locf=type2));
 do until (last.personid);
   set  combine1;
   by id stock;
   locf=coalesce(type2,locf);
   output;
 end;
run;

    data combine2;
    set combine2;
    if month^=fmonth then type2=.;
    run;

data combine2;
set combine2;
if type1=1 or type2=1 then type=1;
else type=0;
run;
```

I tried these codes, the results looks right, but I cannot 100% sure. Additionally, as you can see, my codes are relative long and complex. So could anyone give me some suggestions about the code?

Comment: Shouldn't the new flag be true for ID=2 and STOCK=1?  Month number 1 appears three years in a row: 2011,2012 and 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit of brute force way.  For this example I just limited it to the years 2009 to 2015 in your example, but you could just expand the pattern to allow more years. You could use macro logic to generate the wallpaper aspects of the code.

First generate an array you can index by YEAR and MONTH and populate the variables with 1 when the month it represents has a trade.  Then check if the series of values for the same month across the years ever has three 1's in a row.  You can use two DOW loops to process the data. The first one populates the array and the second tests the array and sets the new flag variable.

```
data want ;
 do until(last.stock) ;
   set have ;
   by id stock;
   array months [1:12,2009:2015] 
     m1y2009-m1y2015 m2y2009-m2y2015 m3y2009-m3y2015 m4y2009-m4y2015
     m5y2009-m5y2015 m6y2009-m6y2015 m7y2009-m7y2015 m8y2009-m8y2015
     m9y2009-m9y2015 m10y2009-m10y2015 m11y2009-m11y2015 m12y2009-m12y2015
   ;
   months[month(trandate),year(trandate)]=1;
 end;
 do until(last.stock);
   set have;
   by id stock;
   select (month(trandate));
     when (1) flag=0 ne index(cats(of m1y:),'111');
     when (2) flag=0 ne index(cats(of m2y:),'111');
     when (3) flag=0 ne index(cats(of m3y:),'111');
     when (4) flag=0 ne index(cats(of m4y:),'111');
     when (5) flag=0 ne index(cats(of m5y:),'111');
     when (6) flag=0 ne index(cats(of m6y:),'111');
     when (7) flag=0 ne index(cats(of m7y:),'111');
     when (8) flag=0 ne index(cats(of m8y:),'111');
     when (9) flag=0 ne index(cats(of m9y:),'111');
     when (10) flag=0 ne index(cats(of m10y:),'111');
     when (11) flag=0 ne index(cats(of m11y:),'111');
     when (12) flag=0 ne index(cats(of m12y:),'111');
     otherwise ;
   end;
   output;
  end;
  drop m: ;
run;
```